# Limit or conditionally modify longitude values in st_buffer

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, r-sf

I have a series of lines with endpoints at 180 degrees longitude. When buffering using st_buffer the buffers extend beyond the 180 degree threshold creating non-sensical polygons. I'd like to use the 180 degree threshold as a cutoff so the buffers just end there.

```
LineA<-st_linestring(matrix(c(179,179.2,180,66.5,66.2,66),3))%>%
  st_sfc()%>%
  st_as_sf()%>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

LineB<-st_linestring(matrix(c(179,179.8,180,66.9,66.4,66.5),3))%>%
  st_sfc()%>%
  st_as_sf()%>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

Lines<-bind_rows(LineA,LineB)

Buffer<-st_buffer(Lines,500,endCapStyle='FLAT')
```

[Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwh3v.png)

[Global buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Fdy.png)

[Buffer at lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghiI.png)

[Buffer across 180 threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBUwc.png)

[Desired Buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib3Sv.png)

I've tried conditionally modifying the geometry of the buffered polygon (via mutate and assignment functions) so the points ending up on the other side of the globe (longitudes with values of -179.xxx values) are conditionally set to 179.9999999 to form the desired buffer but haven't been able to find a way to do so.

There may be more be better approaches to achieving that result but I'm not sure how to get there.

edit for context:
I will then be using the created buffers as zones when calculating zonal summaries of a raster. Most of the lines/buffers in this analysis work appropriately (they do not cross the meridian), so looking for a fix that addresses that subset causing issues.

Comment: You might take a look at `?sf::st_break_antimeridian` , or possibly `sf::st_shift_longitude` to see if it meets you use and desired results.

Comment: Thanks Chris, adding st_shift_longitude created the correct buffers. They extend beyond the meridian slightly but that isn't an issue for my analysis.

If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: As you've done the MRE, applied the suggestion, perhaps comparing the two as applicable to your use case, I think you should write the answer, come back in a couple of days and accept  it. Writing about it helps solidify you understanding, and through time gives your an archive of solutions to refer. Welcome to Stackoverflow.